# $(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2 \leq 2(1-\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i)$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Let $x_i$ and $y_i$ be real numbers and $x_1^2+...+x_n^2=1=y_1^2+...+y_n^2$. Prove that: 
$$(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2 \leq 2(1-\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i)$$
Actually, I know that the right part is $||.||_2$ of $x$ and $y$ but I don't know if it helps or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use Lagrange's identity:

$\mathbb (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_i\sum_{j=1}^{n}y^2_j-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_iy_j-y_ix_j)^2 $

As $x^2_1+x^2_2+\cdots+x^2_n=1=y^2_1+y^2_2+\cdots+y^2_n$, so fitting this into above gives,

$\mathbb (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i)^2=1-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_iy_j-y_ix_j)^2 $

$\implies \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_iy_j-y_ix_j)^2=2(1-\mathbb (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i)^2)$

$\implies \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_iy_j-y_ix_j)^2}{1+(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i)}\leq2(1-\mathbb (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i))$

As $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i\leq 1$ (using Cauchy Schwarz) so,

$\implies \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_iy_j-y_ix_j)^2}{2}\leq2(1-\mathbb (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i))$

$\frac{2(x_2y_1-x_1y_2)^2}{2}\leq2(1-\mathbb (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i))$ because term on left side appears twice.

Hence,

$(x_2y_1-x_1y_2)^2\leq2(1-\mathbb (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i))$