# Prove that the sum of the following is less than 1

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider two sequence of positive numbers  {$a_i$}$_{i=1}^{n}$

and {$b_i$}$_{i=1}^{n}$ such that

$\sum$$_{k=1}^{n}$ ${a_k}^p$ $= 1$

and $\sum$$_{k=1}^{n}$ ${b_k}^q$ $= 1$

where p and q are conjugate exponents.

Prove that

$\sum$$_{k=1}^{n}$ ${a_k}{b_k}$ $\leq 1$

My method

$(a_1^p + a_2^P + ... + a_n^p) = 1$  and $(b_1^q + b_2^q + ... + b_n^q) = 1$

If I multiply the two equations I'll have

$\sum$$_{k=1}^{n}$ ${a_k}^{p} {b_k}^{q}$ $\leq 1$

but how do I get to the answer after that.

Comment: What kind of numbers are $p$ and $q$, and are they related in any way?

Comment: that explanation is not given here. but I'll suppose they are conjugate exponents

Comment: [Cauchy–Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality) can be used to prove this for $p=q=2$ (which is then used as a lemma in proving something [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2499428/318073)). Then maybe [Hölder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder%27s_inequality) (generalization) can be used to prove it for all $p,q$.

Comment: Thanks I'll  try using holder

Comment: It will hold when $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, but not in general.  Example $a_1=a_2=b_1=b_2=.7937$ and $p=q=3$ while $n=2$.  Then $\sum a_k^3=\sum b^3_k=1$, while $\sum a_kb_k=1.2599$